# What the difference between iCal4j/biweekly and google-rfc-2445?

Tags: java, icalendar, rfc5545, ical4j, rfc2445

Right now I'm using [google-rfc-2445](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-rfc-2445/) library to evaluate recurring events, and generate actual dates, for example to know when will occur event defined by following RRULE: `RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-1`

I'm using [biweekly](https://github.com/mangstadt/biweekly) library to generate *.ics files. Actually it does same as [iCal4j](http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/introduction.html) but API much more easy to use.

I see that both libraries have at some level interchangeable functionality, so my question, can I use single library (iCal4j/biweekly) for both tasks? Generate recurring events and export/import *.ics files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[google-rfc-2445](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-rfc-2445/) focuses primarily on evaluating recurrence rules, while [biweekly](https://github.com/mangstadt/biweekly) and [iCal4j](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j) focus on working with iCalendar files as a whole.

If your goal is to generate iCalendar files, then you should use biweekly or iCal4j.  If you need to iterate over the dates that are in a recurrence rule, then use google-rfc-2445.  If you just need to **create** a recurrence rule, you don't need google-rfc-2445.

biweekly allows you to iterate over the dates in a recurrence rule (see code below).  It uses google-rfc-2445 to do this.

```
ICalendar ical = ...
VEvent event = ical.getEvents().get(0);
RecurrenceRule rrule = event.getRecurrenceRule();
Iterator<Date> it = rrule.getDateIterator(event.getDateStart().getValue());
```